# How to Extend javascript object methods

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this object

```
var X = {
   a:function(args){
    },
   b:function(args){
    },
   c: ...... etc
}

X.a() // will do somthing
```

I want to modify the method that it will do one more statement say "counter++"

So

```
var oldX = X.a();
X.a =function(args){
       oldX(args);
        counter++;
}
```

if i want to make this change to all the methods of the object X . **So how can i do this by looping through the object like**?

```
for(var i in X){

}
```

when i tried it by storing in an ooldArray of methods but while executing it will replace all the method with lastone ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm completely sure the behavior you want should be achieved using prototypical inheritance. But I'm know nothing about your architecture and requirements, so here is the solution written in the way you want:

```
var x = {
       a: function(){
           console.log('x.a')
       }, 
       b: function(){
           console.log('x.b')
       }
    },
    oldx = {},
    key;

for (key in x) {
    oldx[key] = x[key];
    (function(key){
        x[key] = function(){
            oldx[key].apply(this, arguments);
            console.log('x.new_'+key);
        }
    })(key);

}

x.a();
x.b();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i also tried this... but when i am calling it like 
"x.a();gives --> x.b x.new_b" ----"x.b()gives -->x.b x.new_b" . All the method is getting replaced with last one.

Comment: The code above will output: x.a x.new_a x.b x.new_b. Exactly what you want.

Comment: actualy what is the last for loop for "
for (key in x) {
    x[key]();
}
" ..? please check http://jsfiddle.net/KEqw4/1/

Comment: @SarathSaleem Forgotten to capture the key variable by closure. Fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what you want:

```
var x = {
a:function(){
    return "this is a";
},
b:function(){
    return "this is b";
},
c:function(){
    return "this is c";
}
}

for(var abc in x)
{
    alert(abc);
}
```

Comment: OP wants to extend methods, not to just call them.